# Why shall we Explicitly cast in Java in case of parsing JSON or webservice responses?

Tags: java, json, web-services, google-maps, casting

I'm trying to parse Json reply from Google GeoCoding API using org.JSON in Java. Reply stream is either JSONObject or JSONArray as per the API specs (there is no problem till here).

Q1: But every time, I have to explicitly cast them (Please see last line; If I don't its giving compiler errors). Is it the limitation with the API or with any such Streams from such web Services? If possible please explain why do we have to explicitly cast in Java. and what are all the cases we have to do this?

Q2: Is there anyway I can build JSON tree directly from the Reply Stream from the Web Service rather reading it into a Buffer Object first( Here I used String Buffer) and later building JSON Tree.

For your ref:
Google's Geocode library

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

- Example
- http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway
- Input Partial Address
- OutPut List of possible Address Match

  ```
  import org.json.JSONArray;  
  import org.json.JSONException;  
  import org.json.JSONObject;  
  public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {

  String address = getUserInput();        //assert address = "1602+Amphitheatre+Parkway"

  String URLString = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=";

  String results = fetchSuggestions(URLString, address);      // This has fetched entire reply from Google GeoCode API


  // parse the Result String to JSON
  JSONObject myJSONResult = new JSONObject(results);
  for (int i = 0; i <((JSONArray) myJSONResult.get("results")).length(); i++) 
      System.out.println(((JSONObject) ((JSONArray) myJSONResult.get("results")).get(i)).get("formatted_address"));
  ```

  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1: There are methods that do typecasting for you (just read API doc - http://www.json.org/java/):

```
JSONArray arr = myJSONResult.getJSONArray("results");
JSONObject obj = arr.getJSONObject(i);
```

You need typecasting because Java (in general, any OO-language) can't have two methods with same signature (name and arguments) and different return types, which are not in the one hierarchy tree. So, method `get` can return `JSONObject` or `JSONArray`, but it's impossible to have one method returning both types without referencing to their common parent - `Object`. It could be solved by another API design with one class for arrays and objects, but it's not handy too.

Q2: Yes, but use `javax.json` - http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/package-summary.html. (you need to download and install any implementation and hack into HTTP processing to get HTTP-body stream and pass to library methods: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/Json.html).